# RegionIntersection extremely slow before throwing error

Tags: regions, mesh, intersection

I am dealing with polygons admitted by using other [region functions](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/DerivedRegions.html) (like `RegionDifference`), some of which have insidious problems.

Consider those below;

```
pA = Polygon[{{45.36842200621874, -19.99999846732962}, {46., -92.}, {45., -93.}, {98., -151.}, {202., -162.6389941886955}, {202., -115.45591028150943}, {165., -116.}, {120., -49.}, {120.62032087153082, -19.999999255934014}}];
pB = Polygon[{{98., -151.}, {66.58627519630939, -116.62271625256498}, {55.79313759815469, -104.8113581262825}, {50.39656879907734, -98.90567906314125}, {49.278708119268465, -97.68235982863342}}];
```

Note that `pB` is very thin and is a result of `RegionDifference` being [infamously unreliable](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1934530). So to visualise it below, I'll draw a thick line between its points.

> [image]

I now wish to find the intersection of these Polygons, but alas, calling

```
RegionIntersection[pA, pB]
```

takes **303 seconds** to spit out error:

```
BoundaryMeshRegion::dupbcl: The cell Line[{{2,1}}] was given in more than one boundary.
```

Clearly `pB` is malformed and an adversarial input for `RegionIntersection`. What exactly is wrong with it, and is there a way I can efficiently determine it is a bogus output of `RegionDifference` to be discarded?

Answer (score 1):

The following succeeds. First, we use exact numbers and convert polygons to `ImplicitRegion`s.

```
pA = RegionConvert[Polygon[Rationalize[{{45.36842200621874, -19.99999846732962}, 
{46., -92.}, {45., -93.}, {98., -151.}, {202., -162.6389941886955}, 
{202., -115.45591028150943}, {165., -116.}, {120., -49.}, 
{120.62032087153082, -19.999999255934014}}, 0]], "Implicit"];
pB = RegionConvert[ Polygon[Rationalize[{{98., -151.}, {66.58627519630939, 
-116.62271625256498}, {55.79313759815469, -104.8113581262825}, 
{50.39656879907734, -98.90567906314125}, {49.278708119268465, 
-97.68235982863342}}, 0]], "Implicit"];
```

Now we easily find the intersection

```
ri = RegionIntersection[pA, pB];
```

and plot it

```
Region[ri]
```

[image]

This looks like an interval in 2D. Indeed,

```
RegionMeasure[ri, 2]
```

> `0`

and

```
RegionMeasure[ri, 1] // N
```

> `67.7041`

Comment: The same `RegionMeasure[ri,2]==0` is obtained without `Rationalize`.